Read/Write functions in Hardware Interface can not achieve desired frequency when writing to hardware
I am working on overriding read and write functions of the hardware interface for using ros2_control.
In the write function I am sending write commands to a CAN bus.
To be exact I am calling this function in my write function:
VCI_Transmit(vci_device_type_, vci_device_ind_, can_port_idx_, send_frame, 3)
Now When I timed this function in a standalone cpp program it took less than a milisecond to execute this
However when I call the same function inside the write function it sometimes takes about a second to complete the call. Consequently, the frequency of my read and write calls drop drastically to about 3 Hz from the set 10, 50 or 100 Hz.
Could it be that my VCI_Transmit call is a blocking call? If it is, what could be done to achieve the desired frequency for my control loop?

Could you give some information about the library you are using, where is VCI_Transmit() coming from?

well this function comes from a can library libcontrolcan.so (https://github.com/AbangLZU/can_control/tree/master/can_control_node/lib)
this could be any write call but if it is a blocking call how do we navigate our way in maintaining the desired frequency?

If it is blocking, then there is no way to get around that. What you can do is to add debug output (console log, DataTamer, whatever) and report the passed time of VCI_Transmit. If you want to publish it to a ROS topic, then consider a RT Publisher or you might effect your RT loop just with the publisher.
